# Electrical near a traditional fireplace

Tags: electrical, receptacle, fireplace

We are currently adding built-ins around a traditional fireplace. We wanted to move outlets from the floor next to the fireplace up so we can add lighting above the built-ins. When we started to cut open the drywall we noticed the electrical is in a metal conduit. Is this for safety purposes because of the fireplace, or could we still run a heat resistant wire outside the conduit? Any specific restrictions with running electrical near a traditional fireplace? Thank you!

Comment: Your location might be important, certain places(like Chicago/NY) require all wire to be in conduit.  If in a wooden stud wall, then think the fireplace does not matter.

Comment: We are in FL and it's a cinder block wall with a home built in 1988. Not sure if this has to do with the fireplace or due to it being against cinder block.

Comment: Photos might help. This _sounds_ like simple old-style metallic conduit wiring, predating the use of NMC cables, but context may matter. Knowing where you want to mount the new outlet may also matter. Photos!